# Gun barrel with single bullet probability problem

Tags: probability

I came across following problem on the book

> A single bullet is put into a 6 chamber revolver. The barrel is randomly spun so that each chamber is equally likely to be under the hammer. Two players take turns
> to pull the trigger—with the gun
> unfortunately pointing at one’s own head. The person who gets killed loses. We will spin the barrel again after every trigger pull. Will you choose to be the first or the second player? And what is your probability of loss?

The solution given is:

> The difference is that each run now becomes independent. Assume that the first player’s probability of losing is $p$, then the second player’s probability of losing is $1-p$. Let’s condition the probability on the first person’s first trigger pull. He has $1/6$ probability of losing in this run. Otherwise, he essentially becomes the second player in the game with new (conditional) probability of losing $1-p$. That happens with probability $5/6$. That gives us $p=1\times 1/6+(1-p)\times 5/6 \rightarrow p=6/11$.
>
> So, you should choose to be the second player and have 5/11 probability of losing.

**Q1.** Am simply not getting this. Especially "He has $1/6$ probability of losing in this run." If a person pulls a trigger, he has $1/6$ probability of winning as there is only one bullet.

I tried it this way:

> Probability of winning for first player:
>
> $$1/6 + (5/6)^2 \times 1/6 + (5/6)^4  \times 1/6=0.36$$
>
> Probability of winning for second player:
>
> $$5/6 \times 1/6 + (5/6)^3 \times 1/6 + (5/6)^5  \times 1/6=0.30$$
>
> Explaining the term $(5/6)^2 \times 1/6$: $5/6$ for player 1 not winning in first pull, $5/6$ for player 2 not winning in second pull and 1/6 for player 1 winning in 3rd pull.

**Q2.** Where did I do wrong?

Comment: I suppose it depends on one's outlook, but traditionally shooting yourself would be interpreted as losing.

Comment: "single bullet " and  "with the gun unfortunately pointing at one’s own head" The prob. that a player kill himself (lose) is obviously 1/6.

Comment: @BrianMoehring tacky, but witty

Answer (score 1):

## Q1

> "He has 1/6 probability of losing in this run."

As your book says:

> The person who gets killed loses

since the person with a gun kills himself with probability 1/6, he loses with probability 1/6 on his turn immediately.

## Q2

They keep playing until one is killed, so your method requires summing infinite geometric series which (computationally) boils down to the 1st method.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the game - this is Russian Roulette, in which a person points a gun at *themselves* and loses if they get shot. With 1 bullet in a 6 chamber gun, each player has a 1/6 chance of losing on each pull of the trigger, assuming the cylinder is spun (randomized) each round.

Furthermore, every round of the game is identical. If you and I both pull the trigger and survive, we are back to the *exact same* situation we started with in the first round. Because of this, it's not necessary to examine an infinite series of rounds, we can just examine the *relative probability* of me losing versus you losing in a single round, and basically ignore the probability that nobody loses. If nobody loses, we're back to square one which has the same relative probabilities of loss for each player. Eventually, one player will lose, and their overall probability of losing is just the relative probability of losing in any one round, since those probabilities never change.